# How to build multiple apps in one project with common Services and dynamic Styles?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I do have three different Apps which are separated from each other. 
Now I would like to add them in one single project/app, and I also would like to be able - in a way - to change the layout/css/scss dynamically.
In the other hand the apps should have some common services.

I use this kind of structure:

```
  /dashboard
     angular-cli.json
     ...
     /src
        /app
           app.component.css
           app.component.html
           app.component.spec
           app.component.ts
           app.module.ts
        /xxx
           xxx.component.css
           xxx.component.html
           xxx.component.spec
           xxx.component.ts
           xxx.module.ts
        /yyy
           yyy.component.css
           yyy.component.html
           yyy.component.spec
           yyy.component.ts
           yyy.module.ts
        /common-services
        main.ts
```

The `ng test --sm=false` works fine.. no errors and I can also build and start the app specifying which one I would like to serve: `ng serve xxx`.

So the issues I'am facing now are:

1. how can I server the psecific app in the browser.. for the moment it goes automatically to first app, not to `xxx` which I did run with `ng serve`
2. How can I create common services for all three apps and where should 
   they be saved based on my structure?
3. How can I be able to change the layout of the three apps based 
   on a kind of config Style (css/scss) file or something similar

**`angular-cli.json`**:

```
    {
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
      "name": "dashboard"
    },
    "apps": [
         {
            "name": "app",
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "yyy",
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
              "assets": [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "styles": [
                "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "lint": [
      {
          "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
      },
      {
          "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
      },
      {
          "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
      }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

**`main.ts`**:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { XxxModule } from './xxx/xxx.module';
import { YyyModule } from './yyy/yyy.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: What are exact problems you're having with this approach? Since xxx and yyy are NgModule modules, you load them in `main` module.

Comment: For instance, I'am facing now an issue when I run the test `ng  test --sm=false`. Here is the error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: This can be anything. If you have specific problems, address them directly and consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Otherwise the question is too broad and cannot gain a quality answer. It looks like you're using Angular CLI but the question doesn't mention even this important fact.

Comment: @estus: The error occurs immediately after adding multi apps to the main one and editing `angular.cli.json` the Test was running successfully just a couple of seconds before and also `ng serve -prod`. 
Of course I'am using `angular.cli`. The App/main app has been created (with Angular CLI) couple of weeks ago, and now the requirements are to expand it to multi apps. I don't think that there are users who would build an Angular app without Angular CLI. The error might affect something else, but the reason in my opinion would be first the multi apps added and the changes in `angular-cli.json`

Comment: Of course, there are users who don't use CLI, and they can't read your thoughts. The fact that some error like `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` happens in your case says nothing to users who read the question. The question should contain clear problem statement. Since it's complex problem, it requires to contain a way to replicate the problem as well - a repo, etc. Otherwise the question is considered off-topic, because the problem doesn't make sense for anyone but you. I guess it's not your first day on SO, so you already know how the things work.

Comment: @estus: I agree with you in general. I might have missed posting more info to make the question and the issue more clear for the SO users. My Bad.
I might edit the question once more and describe the exact use-case with more details and the issue(s) I'am facing. The issue with `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` was the answer to your question in the comment. I agree with you, in a way, that it normally hasn't to do with the main question itself.

Comment: Ok. Keep in mind that it's very different for CLI and non-CLI projects. Possible problems and their solutions are different as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157680/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-estus).

Comment: The question still requires http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with real code - a repo or something, because in its current abstract state it's more like, 'looks ok to me, that's how it should be done'. 1) you can't do that, if xxx is supposed to served as a separate from app, it should be build and run separately from main, like `cd xxx && ng serve` 2) in 'common' folder or as a separate NPM package (possibly local) 3) unclear, totally depends on the app

Answer (score 1):

i think there is an --app option for several command
here is a good example for that to create and build multiple apps https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/

Comment: Yes, I did read this blog... and this where I got the posted link to the gitHub repo. It's not bad, but one of my targets is to be able to create a common service for all the apps in one project.